# Segmentation fault at first gl* call in LWJGL code

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I am trying to create a program with LWJGL and OpenGL 3. However, when my code gets to the following line:

```
program = glCreateProgram();
```

My program exits with the following output:

```
Version.getVerson() => 3.1.2 build 29
glfwInit() => true
glfwCreateWindow() => long
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007faa30c86a67, pid=15863, tid=0x00007faa5a409700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [liblwjgl_opengl.so+0x43a67]  Java_org_lwjgl_opengl_GL20_glCreateProgram+0x7
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/tague/IdeaProjects/Jaav/hs_err_pid15863.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I tried to add this line to my code, directly after my `glfwMakeContextCurrent`:

```
System.out.println("glGetString(GL_VERSION) => " + glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

But now, the program simply exits with a segfault *there* instead.

I am using the following GLFW window hints:

```
glfwDefaultWindowHints();

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);  // Hide window at the start.
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // Window is resizable.
```

**Edit: Here's the complete program, excluding things that aren't being called.**

**Main.java**:

```
package me.tague.jaav;

import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.system.*;

import java.nio.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class Main {

    public long window;
    private Mesh main;

    // Run the actual LWJGL app.
    public void run () {
        System.out.println("Version.getVerson() => " + Version.getVersion());

        init();

        // System.out.println("glGetString(GL_VERSION) => " + glGetString(GL_VERSION)); // <=== ANOTHER SOURCE OF THE ERROR!!! 

        float[] mainVerts = {
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
        };
        main = new Mesh(mainVerts);

        // ...
    }

    private void init () {
        // Print GLFW errors to System.err.
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        // Set up GLFW.
        if (!glfwInit()) throw new IllegalStateException("glfwInit() => false");
        else System.out.println("glfwInit() => true");

        glfwDefaultWindowHints();

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);  // Hide window at the start.
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // Window is resizable.

        // Create the window.
        window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Hello!", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL) throw new RuntimeException("glfwCreateWindow() => NULL");
        else System.out.println("glfwCreateWindow() => long");

        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
        });

        try (MemoryStack stack = stackPush()) {
            IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1);
            IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1);

            glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

            GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

            // Center the window
            glfwSetWindowPos(
                    window,
                    (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                    (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
            );
        }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSwapInterval(-1);
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }
}
```

**Mesh.java**:

```
package me.tague.jaav;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

public class Mesh {

    public Material material;

    public Mesh(float[] vertices) {
        // Set up a default, generic material.
        material = new Material();

        // ... some more stuff that isn't called yet.
    }
}
```

**Material.java**:

```
package me.tague.jaav;

import java.io.*;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;

public class Material {
    private int program;

    public Material () {
        makeProgram("shaders/generic/vert.gl", "shaders/generic/frag.gl");
    }

    /**
     * Make an OpenGL Program, given vertex and fragment source files.
     * @param vert The filename for the vertex shader to use.
     * @param frag The filename for the fragment shader to use.
     * @return     The ID for the loaded program.
     */
    private void makeProgram(String vert, String frag) {
        // Create the program in OpenGL.
        program = glCreateProgram(); // <==== THE SOURCE OF THE ERROR !!!!!

        // ... more stuff that never runs
    }    
}
```

Comment: When I get these with LWJGL, it's usually because I've handed OpenGL a buffer (Vertex Buffer Object, VBO, etc.) with an error in it (bad data, null pointer, etc.).  Probably we need to see your buffer initialization, not your GLFW initialization.  Of course the error could be anywhere at all, so...

Comment: @markspace literally no other gl* calls are being called in my code before this `glCreateProgram()`, so there's not much for me to show. If you want to see the whole file that this error comes from: https://gist.github.com/emctague/fdbb08089a5cecf780d9b73b8a68030a

Comment: I think you should add the complete program to the question then, if that's all there is to it.  However, the code you linked to has no main entry point, so I'm sure there's some bits you haven't told us about.

Comment: Please post the GLFW window creation and context initialization code.

Comment: Short Self-Contained Compilable Example: http://sscce.org/  How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @markspace Alright, I've posted the entire code (cutting out some bits that aren't actually called because the errors happen first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: I was missing `GL.createCapabilities()` in my `init`. This function is required before any gl* calls are made.